# Binary Trees - difference between insert and mirror?

Tags: c, pointers, binary-tree

What manipulations are we doing in `insert`/`delete` that we aren't in `mirror`?

By `mirror` I'm referring to switching the left and right child of every single node in the tree.

The reason I'm asking is that when it comes to an `insert`, if you don't save the root returned by the function, it leads to errors. The same is not true of `mirror`. I assumed `mirror` would have the same requirement (returning the root node), but that is not the case. Why is that?

Here's my code if it's relevant (the `insert` is implemented for a BST):

Insert:

```
Node *insert(Node *root,int val)
{
    Node *newNode=NULL;



    if(root==NULL)
    {
        newNode=(Node*) malloc(sizeof(Node));

        newNode->value=val;
        newNode->left=NULL;
        newNode->right=NULL;
        return newNode;
    }

    if(root->value>val)
    {
        root->left=insert(root->left,val);
    }
    else
    {
        root->right=insert(root->right,val);
    }

    return root;

}
```

Mirror:

```
void mirror(Node *root)
{
    Node *temp_left;
    if(root==NULL)
        return;

    temp_left=root->left;
    root->left=root->right;
    root->right=temp_left;

    mirror(root->left);
    mirror(root->right);

}
```

Comment: This is not a BTree.  It's a *binary* tree.  __VERY__ different structures.  Please edit your title or the contents of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice the line:

```
root->left=insert(root->left,val);
```

Here you are assigning the result of `insert()` to `root->left`. You need `insert()` to return a `node*` pointer here, or else we would have no idea where `malloc` placed the new node in memory, and so you wouldn't be able to add the node to the tree.

On the other hand, `mirror` only traverses the tree recursively and swaps some already-existing pointers. You need never assign the result `mirror()` to a variable.